# GROUP BY not working + Three table selection

Tags: sql, group-by

I have three tables
**Sessions**

- DriverID
- PayerID
- DateRegistration
- SessionID
- PayerEmail

**Driver**

- DriverID
- PayerID (one payer can have multiple drivers)
- Program
- Language

**Payer**

- PayerID
- Email (I want to get email from here, as it can be changed and if yes, data is changed here, but not reciprocally in Sessions)

I want to get the table with
Driver ID
Payer ID
Email
Program
Language
No of days from date of registration to today
No of sessions (no of session IDs)

What I have until now is:

```
SELECT days_between(D.DateRegistration, today()) as No.of.Days, COUNT (S.SessionID) as No.of.Sessions, D.DriverID, D.PayerID,   D.Language, D.Program, S.PayerEmail    (-- P.Email, commented) 
FROM Driver as D,  Sessions as S ( -- Payer as P, commented)
WHERE D.DriverID = S.DriverID
GROUP BY (S.DriverID)
```

I have two questions:

1. My COUNT does not work, I guess because of GROUP BY, but I do not know how to proceed
2. Is there a possibility to match also the third table like this or in similar simple way?

I am new to SQL and this is the best I was able to do until now.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh, understood, but changing it to GROUP BY (D.DriverID) does not change the issue. Or do I understand you wrong?

Comment: @Zuzkatel Depends what the issue is. "does not work" Doesn't tell us what goes wrong for you

Comment: "I am new to SQL" Yet you use 30 year old syntax. Please use explicit `JOIN` syntax, it is easier to read, easier to write and easier to change

Comment: @HoneyBadger, thanks for comments. Does not work means that this comment: Error Details: Parsing of SQL query failed. Please check the SQL syntax.

Comment: @HoneyBadger well than, new to sql means that I did not get to JOIN until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid implicit joins because it is possible to get accidental cross joins which then return incorrect results, especially if you have a lot of joins in the query.

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()) to group the result-set by one or more columns, so you should mention the columns in the SELECT clause, in the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT 
D.DriverID, 
D.PayerID,  
D.Language, 
D.Program, 
P.PayerEmail, 
days_between(D.DateRegistration, today()) as No.of.Days,
COUNT (S.SessionID) as No.of.Sessions,  
FROM Driver as D
LEFT JOIN Sessions AS S ON D.DriverID = S.DriverID
LEFT JOIN Payer AS P ON P.PayerID = S.PayerID
GROUP BY 
D.DriverID, 
D.PayerID,  
D.Language, 
D.Program, 
S.PayerEmail,
days_between(D.DateRegistration, today())
```